# Where are my python mysql file queries updating? Updates not showing in MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have got MySQL installed on my computer and I have been successfully running queries on MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client

[image]

Now I am trying some python scripting, I believe I have done the pip installs for the necessary modules, no errors are being returned when I run the code below

However the database in MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client isn't updating when I run the code

**Code example 1**

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='root',
                             db='news',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO headline_titles (Title, Language, Translation, Url) VALUES ('Dummy Title 2','German', 'Dummy Translation 2', 'Dummy Url 2');"
        cursor.execute(sql)

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.

finally:
    connection.close()
```

**Code example 2**

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
user="root",         # your username
passwd="root",  # your password
db="news")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("INSERT INTO headline_titles (Title, Language, Translation, Url) VALUES ('Dummy Title 2','German', 'Dummy Translation 2', 'Dummy Url 2');")

db.close()
```

I am not sure if the above code links to the MySQL software installed on my computer and the default path for that, or is trying to save to path of the python file.

As I want to send the python file to somebody, I would like this code to execute to a database saved in the path of the python file e.g. in the same folder as the python file.

I have tried saving a text file as a MySQL file extension and running the above, but it doesn't seem to be updating.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL needs a server to run.

on that you have your database news, this you can backup and send.

But the person that receives the database dump needs to install also a server and import it.

Another option would be to send a docker image, which would everything onboard, but this needs also a software that runs the docker image.

You can think about use  a web server with an attached database, so that only one Server exists, but as you shouldn't expose your database, you need a REST api, that gathers data and sends to your program.

But as you want to send your program with data, you can  think about using sqllite, a file based database, that you can deliver with your program. no need to install more programs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was missing a db.commit() command because I was using an SQL statement to insert records. When I added the db.commit() command it has updated my database in the MySQL server folder, and those databases are hidden files. I am still trying to figure out how to update a copy of that database in the path of the python file. On a previous assignment I have been able to query data from a database in the path of a python file, but I am very rusty at this.